# MATLAB fails to display plot, but Microsoft Excel can

Tags: excel, matlab, matlab-figure

My goal is to recreate a plot in Excel in MATLAB. In excel, I have coded:

```
1/(1 + (SINH($B$4^(1/2)*(1 - C6)^(1/2)))^2/(4*C6*(1-C6)))
```

In the above, cell B4 has the value 10. C6 through C500 take values starting at 0 upto 5 in succession (so C6 would be 0, and C500 would be C6+0.01+0.01+0.01... = 5), with increments of 0.01.

In other words, the column 'C' runs from 0 to 5 in increments of 0.01 (which is the x axis of the plot). I then apply the above formula to column C to obtain the graph below.

Excel displays the following, which is correct:
[image: Excel Graph of Equation Above]

However, attempting to recreate the same graph in MATLAB results in an empty plot (which I show after the code)

```
 v = 10
 x = [0:0.01:5]
 plot(x, 1/(1 + (sinh(v^(1/2)*(1 - x).^(1/2))).^2/(4*x.*(1-x))), 'LineWidth', 2)

 grid on
 xlabel('x')
 ylabel('Transmittance')
```

[image: MATLAB Problem]

I have tried restarting my computer, restarting MATLAB to no avail.
Thanks for your guidance!

Comment: You need `./` instead of `7`; twice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot two `.`'s:

```
1./(1 + (sinh(v^(1/2)*(1 - x).^(1/2))).^2./(4*x.*(1-x)))
 ^                                       ^
```

I advise you to first evaluate the expression and store in a varable, then you can immediately see that without this dot you will a single value. Plotting a vector and a single value doesn't really produce anything usable, but also does not throw an error, so it's tricky to debug without having the variable in the workspace.

Comment: Thank you so much! It plots now! How do I learn where I must use my dot

Comment: @Matt The dot is needed when you want _element-wise_ operations with `*`, `^` or `/` (also ```\``` but that's used less often element-wise). Without dot they are _matrix_ operations. With `+` there is no dot because matrix addition is the same as element-wise addition. For more information see [here](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/array-vs-matrix-operations.html?lang=en)